# Design on HTML5 canvas - how to speed up rendering

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

So I was under the impression that rendering designs on the HTML5 canvas would be quite fast. I'm using the following code and I would think it would take less than a second to render, but it takes about **2 minutes** total.

Code:

```
 <script>
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas")
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
    maxW = window.innerWidth
    maxH = window.innerHeight
    x = -1
    numLeft = 15

//maxW = 300
//maxH = 300
canvas.setAttribute("width", maxW)
canvas.setAttribute("height", maxH)
ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,.5)"

for(var j = 0; j < maxH; j++){
  for(var i = 0; i < maxW; i++){
    if(numLeft < 0){
      if(x == -1){
        ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(127,127,127,.5)"
        //numLeft += 12
        numLeft += 5
      }
      else{
        ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,.5)"
        //numLeft += 24
        numLeft += 15
      }
      x *= -1
    }
    ctx.fillRect(i,j,i+1,j+1)
    numLeft--
  }
  //numLeft -= 5 this one's crazy :D
  numLeft -= 3
}
```

It's supposed to draw **diagonal stripes in black and grey**. But again, it's taking forever to render and would crash most people's browsers. Any hints as to how to speed this up?

Comment: I don't know whether you intended to or not, but `drawRect(x, y, 1, 1)` fills one pixel - it's `(x, y, w, h)`. This makes for a great speed improvement since you're currently drawing *much* more pixels (width `i + 1` and height `j + 1`, so the amount of pixels you're painting grows quadratically).

Comment: Agreed, you can see the difference in this jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/luisperezphd/eY82y/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since comments can't be accepted as answers as far as I know, I'm posting @pimvdb comment as an answer. The problem was the way `fillRect()` was being called, it was being called as if the all the parameters were coordinates `(x, y, x2, y2)` when in fact the parameters were a combination of coordinates and dimension `(x, y, w, h)`.

I confirmed that this was a major performance problem in your code with with [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/luisperezphd/eY82y).

As mentioned there are other performance improvements you can make like pre-rendering and using line gradients but this addresses the immediate performance problem. In my test on Chrome performance went from 6 seconds to less than one.

Have you tried the [performance suggests on html5rocks.com](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/performance/)?

Comment: No. What are they? (The suggestions, that is.)

Comment: Hey @JaredFarrish the improvements are pretty much the same improvements you find for graphics programming in general. For example instead of re-rendering the same thing multiple times you render it once to it's own canvas and then you just draw that canvas onto your target canvas multiple times. That's actually a technique that can be used for this problem. There is other similar advice like sending all your drawing commands over at once - grouping them essentially.

Answer (score 2):

Pixel based operations are almost always expensive since you have to go through each pixel and color it (1000x1000 size → 1 000 000, a million, pixels!!!). You should always find ways to optimize the performance when you know how the design should look like. You could improve your example by filling the canvas with the color of the wider stripes and then only loop through the pixels that need to be changed (also make sure that `maxH` and `maxW` are the size of the Canvas and not the inner window).

A much simpler and faster approach would be to actually draw the lines using the `moveTo` and `lineTo` commands.